# NoClassDefFoundError for javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse when using java client library

Tags: android, google-api-java-client

I am trying to create a small android application to list my drive contents.

But I was unsuccessful with the play_service library as it was always returning no files (with count 0 when invoking listChildren).

Now when trying to use the google-api-java-library I am facing NoClassDefFoundError for the ServletResponse.

```
new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
```

I have included all the jar from drive-api-jar provided by google. That also includes jetty and jetty-utils.

But after checking the source of jetty, I found out that jetty depends on javax.servlet.http.* for which I was unable find a jar.

So running the application is giving the error. Can anybody point me to right direction? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse is part of the Apache Tomcat libraries (TOMCAT_HOME\lib\servlet-api.jar). You shouldn't use them in an Android Application. What excatly do you want to do with the HttpServletResponse? --- Try adding this to your gradle build script: compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'

Comment: @PhilippEmmermacher Jetty and Jetty utils have dependency on the HttpServletResponse. And the client-library (google-api) is probably using jetty for oauth2.

I don't know much about gradle. As I used either the eclipse ADT or the NDK. Do I need to setup/use additional tools to use gradle?

TIA.

Comment: Gradle is used in Android Studio. Does your Eclipse project use maven? If  not you can find the required jar here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api otherwise you can find the depdency at the same place.

Comment: @PhilippEmmermacher Thank you for your suggestion, I was able to include the jar and bypass the issue for jetty. Now got stuck at another-one :(. Can you post your comment as Answer so that I can accept it. It may help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse is part of the Apache Tomcat libraries (TOMCAT_HOME\lib\servlet-api.jar).

Does your Eclipse project use maven? If not you can find the required jar here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api otherwise you can find the dependency at the same place.